# How to render a partial based on specific link clicked?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm having trouble rendering partials using Ajax/jQuery in my Rails app and am wondering where i'm going wrong.

*Rails 5.2.0*

On my Dashboard view, i'm trying to render partials based on the specific sidebar link item clicked.

In my `views/users/my_dashboard.html.erb`:

```
<li class="sidenav__list-item">
    <%= link_to "Transaction History", transaction_path, :remote: true %>
</li>
```

My partial `_test.html.erb`:

```
<div>
  <p>It works if this shows</p>
</div>
```

and in my `views/users/my_dashboard.js.erb`:

```
$('#render-test').replaceWith("<%= j render 'users/partials_dashboard/test' %>");
```

In my `views/users/my_dashboard.html.erb`, When the `Transaction History` link is clicked, i need it to render its corresponding partial:

```
// replace this div, with the rendered partial

<div id="render-test">
</div>
```

Controller `users_controller.rb`:

```
def my_dashboard
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
end
```

What am i missing?

Comment: what is actually happening, is there any issue or error comes or anything else,  from your description i can understand what you want to do , but what is your issue that part i am not getting. also you can use **$('id').empty.append()** method for rendering partial.

Comment: there aren't any issues coming up at all. when i click on the link, i can see that in the console its making a GET request, but nothing happens.

Comment: @bitdon are you sure that `$('#render-test')` exists on appropriate page? If so, are you sure , that there is only one element with this `'#render-test'`. Try to add to you `my_dashboard.js.erb` `console.log` or `alert('error')` to check that it works.

Answer (score -1):

You can not generate ruby with Javascript, the ruby won't be interpreted. If you really need to something dynamic, then you should consider creating an API route and then, call this API with Jquery

Comment: Are you talking about the js.erb file? Because that’s a ruby file generating JavaScript.